# I uninstalled a network adapter, and now I can't change connect to the internet

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I uninstalled a network adapter because I was having internet issues and a guide said that deleting it would fix my issue. It didn't. Previously, I could connect to a network but not the internet, but now I can't connect to a network at all. I have already tried scanning for hardware changes and restarting my computer, multiple times. None of it has worked.
How do I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Nevermind, I figured it out myself. For anyone having the same issue, find out what model your network card is (you can find it right behind those things that stick out at the back of the computer), go to a device that has internet, google "[model name] drivers", download the driver files to a flash drive, and then plug that flash drive into your computer. Look through the files and you should find an application that says "setup" or something similar. Run that, and the necessary drivers will install and let your computer connect to the internet again. I'm adding this huge addendum because I'm sick of seeing people say "nvm I fixed it" with no elaboration. Hope I could help anyone with the same issue as me.

Comment: Look in Device Manager. Can you see the network card? Is there a red or yellow X by the device?  You may need to try a USB Wired or Wireless card.

Comment: It's not there at all, completely disappeared

Comment: You probably have a hardware issue with your network card. So try a USB card as I suggested.

Comment: @328 - please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.